# How to rename all files with special characters and spaces in a directory?

Tags: linux, shell-script, rename

How can i rename all the files in a specific directory where the files contains blanks spaces and special characters ($ and @) in their names?

I tried the `rename` command as follows to replace all the spaces and special characters with a _:

```
$ ls -lrt
total 464
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 pmautoamtion pmautoamtion 471106 Jul 17 13:14 Bharti Blocked TRX Report Morning$AP@20150716.csv


$ rename -n 's/ |\$|@/_/g' *
$ ls -lrt
total 464
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 pmautoamtion pmautoamtion 471106 Jul 17 13:14 Bharti Blocked TRX Report Morning$AP@20150716.csv
$
```

The command works but won't make any changes in the file names and won't return any error as well. How can in fix this and are there other ways as well?

Comment: You may be expecting the perl rename script (ref: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/prename.1.html) but are instead getting util-linux rename, which does not work the same way.

Comment: rename command has many versions depending on OS. My Centos rename is
 <code>     rename [options] expression replacement file... </code>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `rename` command didn't work for me for unknown reasons and i do not get any other answers for my question, i myself tried to make an effort to make the rename possible. This might not be the best approach to rename the files but it worked for me and this is why i would like to post it as an answer so that if anyone else reads this might get some help to change the file names the way i did.

Now for me, i know that all the files will have a specific text in their names which is the word "Block". Following are the file names before their renaming was done:

```
anks@anks:~/anks$ ls -lrt
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 anks anks   0 Jul 25 14:47 Bharti TRX Block Report$AP@12Jul15.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 anks anks   0 Jul 25 14:47 Bharti TRX Block Report$HP@12Jul15.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 anks anks   0 Jul 25 14:47 Bharti TRX Block Report$CH@12Jul15.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 anks anks   0 Jul 25 14:47 Bharti TRX Block Report$KK@12Jul15.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 anks anks   0 Jul 25 14:48 Bharti TRX Block Report$UW@12Jul15.csv
```

Now i have written a small shell script to make this possible. Following is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH="/home/ebfijjk/anks"

# Put the old filenames in a file.
ls $PATH | grep Block >> oldValues

# Put the new names without " " or "@" or "$" in another file
cat oldValues | sed 's/\$/_/g' | sed 's/\@/_/g' | sed 's/ /_/g' >> newValues

# Create a new file with Old names and New names seperated by a #.
paste -d'#' oldValues newValues >> oldAndNew

# Read the file with both old and new names and rename them with the new names.
while IFS='#'; read oldValue newValue
do
    mv "$oldValue" "$newValue"

done < oldAndNew

rm oldValues newValues oldandNew
```

And that's it, when i run the script, it renames all the file names having blank spaces () or `$` or `@` with `_` instead of these characters.

Comment: you can replace `cat foo | sed S1 | sed S2 | sed S3 >> bar` by `sed -e S1 -e S2 -e S3 foo >> bar`

Comment: @Archemar - or simply `sed 's/[ ()@$]/_/g'` or `sed 'y/ ()@$/_____/'`

Comment: Thank you don_crissti and Archemar for your comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 14):

The `-n` flag is for

> --no-act
>
> No Action: show what files would have been renamed.

So it's normal if you don't have any changes.

Regarding your command, it's working for me:

```
$ touch "a @ test"
$ ls
a @ test
$ rename -n 's/ |\$|@/_/g' *
a @ test renamed as a___test
```

Maybe depending on your shell, you have to escape the |

```
$ rename -n 's/ \|\$\|@/_/g' *
```

Or you can use the `[…]` notation to group characters:

```
$ rename -n 's/[ @\$]/_/g' *
```

Comment: I tried all the three without -n option and still it won't change the name of the file. I doesn't give any error for any of the 3 types mentioned above. Maybe the rename command doesn't work for some reason. Is there any other way to change all the files in a directory with spaces or $ or @ in their names?

Comment: @AnkitVashistha does `rename -n 's/./_/g' *` outputs something?

Comment: It doesn't give anything, no output, no error. It just lands on next command line.

Comment: rename is also not working for me to replace (space) or ':' on Ubuntu 18.04, Bash 4.4.20(1)-release

Comment: all these years and never knew of rename - awesome!

Answer (score 10):

You could try like this:

```
for file in ./*Block*                                       
do echo mv "$file" "${file//[ ()@$]/_}"
done
```

If you're happy with the result, remove the `echo` before `mv` to actually rename the files.

Comment: One of the best solution i have gone through, I was trying for this for so long

Answer (score 4):

looking for a handsome script to remove special characters as well as german special characters, replacing them with universal ones to not remove useful information I've updated the last version of the script which had some minor issues resulting in:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in ./*
do
  infile=`echo "${file:2}"|sed  \
         -e 's|"\"|"\\"|g' \
         -e 's| |\ |g' -e 's|!|\!|g' \
         -e 's|@|\@|g' -e 's|*|\*|g' \
         -e 's|&|\&|g' -e 's|]|\]|g' \
         -e 's|}|\}|g' -e 's|"|\"|g' \
         -e 's|,|\,|g' -e 's|?|\?|g' \
         -e 's|=|\=|g'  `
  outfileNOSPECIALS=`echo "${file:2}"|sed -e 's|[^A-Za-z0-9._-]|_|g'`
  outfileNOoe=`echo $outfileNOSPECIALS| sed -e 's|ö|oe|g'`
  outfileNOae=`echo $outfileNOoe| sed -e 's|ä|ae|g'`
  outfileNOue=`echo $outfileNOae| sed -e 's|ü|ue|g'`
  outfileNOOE=`echo $outfileNOue| sed -e 's|Ö|OE|g'`
  outfileNOAE=`echo $outfileNOOE| sed -e 's|Ä|AE|g'`
  outfileNOUE=`echo $outfileNOAE| sed -e 's|Ü|UE|g'`
  outfileNOss=`echo $outfileNOUE| sed -e 's|ß|ss|g'`
  outfile=${outfileNOss}
  if [ "$infile" != "${outfile}" ]
  then
        echo "filename changed for " $infile " in " $outfile
        mv "$infile" ${outfile}
  fi
done

exit
```

resulting in:

[image]

@don_crissti: He's doing the hokus-pokus with the infile since linux would have it's own issues with handling special characters when moving the filename.

Comment: special characters  ? which ones ?

Comment: Space, At symbol, Ampersand ....

Comment: There is _no problem_ moving a file with a name which contains _special characters_ (including a newline)... You're probably not familiar with the shells (and btw, this has nothing to do with linux, it's a shell feature...)

Comment: mh okay - you're maybe right

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking for a solution to this problem for a while now.  I work on old closed systems that can't have new packages installed.  I don't have the `rename` command.  Finally I wrote a script that appears to work with all keyboard entered special characters.  `~@#$%^&*()-_=+[]{}\|;:",<.>?'`  The script will rename every file and directory in the current directory. It will replace all special characters,except `-_.` with the `_` character.  The `outfile=` line can be modified to use a different character for replacement if desired.  Replace `|_|` with `|.|` to use the `.` character for example.

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in ./*
do
  infile=`echo "${file:2}"|sed  \
         -e 's|"\"|"\\"|g' \
         -e 's| |\ |g' -e 's|!|\!|g' \
         -e 's|@|\@|g' -e 's|*|\*|g' \
         -e 's|&|\&|g' -e 's|]|\]|g' \
         -e 's|}|\}|g' -e 's|"|\"|g' \
         -e 's|,|\,|g' -e 's|?|\?|g' \
         -e 's|=|\=|g'  `
  outfile=`echo "${file:2}"|sed -e 's|[^A-Za-z0-9._-]|_|g'`
  mv "$infile" ${outfile} &
done

exit
```

Answer (score 1):

This one just strip the special characters from filenames

```
for file in *; do mv "$file" `echo $file | tr -cd '.A-Za-z0-9_-'` ; done
ॐNámásté Egész-ség.mkv --> NmstEgsz-sg.mkv
```

put `echo` after `; do` to test before, like:

```
for file in *; do echo mv "$file" `echo $file | tr -cd '.A-Za-z0-9_-'` ; done
```

Another solution:

```
rename -v 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9\.\s_-]//g' *.* && rename -v 's/[\s]/_/g' *.*
ॐNámásté Egész-ség.mkv --> Nmst_Egsz-sg.mkv
```

`-n` option to test before.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very handy tool called [detox](https://github.com/dharple/detox) that will do exactly this transformation/renaming for you.

You can pass it a directory name (eventually recursing) or a pattern of specific files:

```
detox ./
```

or

```
detox *.csv
```

Here is how the transformation is done on the example you gave ("Bharti Blocked TRX Report Morning$AP@20150716.csv")

```
ls *.csv
Bharti_Blocked_TRX_Report_Morning_20150716.csv
```

This package is bundle with [most Linux distributions](https://repology.org/project/detox/versions).

Answer (score 0):

For me on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with bash 4.4.20(1)-release this one-liner worked well to remove spaces, @, : #...

To test (note the `echo` command:

```
for file in ./* ; do if [[ $file == *['!'\ :@#]* ]]; then echo mv "$file" "${file//[ #()@$:]/_}"; fi; done
```

To execute:

```
for file in ./* ; do if [[ $file == *['!'\ :@#]* ]]; then echo mv "$file" "${file//[ #()@$:]/_}"; fi; done
```